# Samsung HW-K450 Soundbar Keeps Turning Off, Even While Using Computer

Tags: x11

I have a Samsung HW-K450 soundbar connected to my computer through an HDMI cord, and my monitor connected to the HDMI output on the soundbar. I had this setup working properly for around a year, but about six months ago the soundbar started turning off spontaneously, even as I was actively using my machine. Usually this occurred around 5-10 minutes after turning the soundbar on. This causes my monitor to lose signal as well, as it comes through the soundbar. No idea what caused this change all of a sudden.

It doesn't do this all the time. There are times where it will repeatedly shut off at the five to ten minute interval mark, but other times where it will stay on as it should and I can use my computer for weeks without having the problem. I have not been able to pinpoint anything in particular that causes the erroneous behavior.

I've tried [the solution mentioned on the Samsung website](https://www.samsung.com/in/support/tv-audio-video/why-sound-bar-switches-off-on-its-own/), but to no avail.

This issue has happened both in i3WM and EXWM. However, there are days where it will happen in one, but when I load the other one it does not happen.

I've noticed if I have music playing the soundbar is not auto powering down.

Finally, running

`xset -q`

returns the following:

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  660    repeat rate:  25
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  5400    cycle:  5400
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/misc,/usr/share/fonts/TTF,/usr/share/fonts/OTF,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 5400    Suspend: 5400    Off: 5400
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

If you have an idea as to what might be causing this and how I could fix it, please let me know.